# Rails 3.2: jQuery UI icons are missing

Tags: jquery-ui, ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline

I've migrated to Rails 3.2.2, deployed all changes to the production server. Now all my jQuery UI icons are missing.

After deploy I did compiled all the resources using this:

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

I've also added //= require jquery-ui to the application.js.

The icons work fine in development env, but doesn't show after deploying to the production server.

Answer (score 0):

Did you move the jquery-UI images to the appropriate directory under

```
app/assets/images/
```

?

Comment: Yes. But I forgot to modify the jQuery UI custom css to use assets pipeline. That turned out to be the reason.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the reason was that I forgot to modify the jQuery UI custom css to use assets pipeline. Here is the fix:

--rename jquery-ui-custom...css to .css.erb
--append <%= assets_pipeline '...png' %> to every place where images are used.